# Vertical alignment in bootstrap header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I know I can do this with a bunch of manual CSS, but am wondering if there's a Bootstrap way to do it.

The Bootstrap site says I can, "create lighter, secondary text in any heading with a generic `<small>` tag or the `.small` class." So I try this in an `<h1>` element, but the vertical alignment goes off as soon as I try floating it to the right:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    Here's some navigation
  </nav>
  <header class="page-header">
    <h1>Main Heading <small class="pull-right">and smaller text</small></h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

I've also tried putting both items in columns (e.g. `.col-md-6`) but this also uses floats, so has the same result. Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use external CSS styles... but if you really really REALLY want to use only build-in bootstrap classes i have something funny for you! Check this out:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    Here's some navigation
  </nav>
  <header class="page-header">
    <h1>Main Heading
        <small class="pull-right">
          <h1 class="media">
            <small>and smaller text</small>
          </h1>
        </small>
    </h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

This is NOT a good solution. This is just a CURIOSITY.

Comment: I actually ended up coming up with an answer based on this one, so I've marked it accepted. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Use **em** units instead, to address different displays:

```
.h1--small {
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

```css
.h1--small {
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  Here's some navigation
</nav>
<header class="page-header">
  <h1>Main Heading <small class="pull-right h1--small">and smaller text</small></h1>
</header>
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

The computed value for your `<h1>` css property `line-height` is equal to `39.6px`, so all you need to do is define the same value in your `<small>` tag:

```
line-height: 39.6px;
```

*To check the computed values of your h1 element just go to dev tools, select your h1, click on computed tab on your top right and look for line-height;*

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.h1--small {
  line-height: 39.6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    Here's some navigation
  </nav>
  <header class="page-header">
    <h1>Main Heading <small class="pull-right h1--small">and smaller text</small></h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: That pixel value is very dependent on display size and resolution; to fix it at a certain value could be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with Kamil's answer, I figured out how to get this working. Apply the `.pull-right` class to a block element and put the `<small>` element inside it:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    Here's some navigation
  </nav>
  <header class="page-header">
    <h1>Main Heading <div class="pull-right"><small>and smaller text</small></div></h1>
  </header>
</body>
```